# font size always to big in iframe (em)

Tags: html, css, iframe

Im making a simple website to be placed in an iframe of someone else his website.
For some reason when the content is placed in the iframe then the font-size is always to big.

On the left you can see it placed in the iframe, on the right it is loaded without the iframe.

[image]

I had:

```
body { 
    font-size: 8px; 
}
```

as well: (where I preferred this one)

```
body { 
    font-size: 62.5%; 
}
```

and used `em` on other classes so they scale according to the font-size set for the body. But in the iframe this does not seem to work.

This is what I see in the inspector:

[image]

In the computed it's 32 pixels. Which is probably 16px default times 2em.
How can I fix this issue with still using 2em for setting the font?
And more important, if anyone knows, what is causing the issue?

Comment: this seems to be caused by a specificity issue. Your `body`'s `font-size` declaration is being overwritten since `#header p` is more specific, so it's using the `2em` instead. Alter it there and see how you get one.

Comment: Yeah but it should use `2em` of the current font size set right?

Comment: I see you have used 10px on the p element, so (as far as I can tell), I believe the font-size should be 2* em's height when M is 10px (20px, roughly). You're mixing up a lot of units, here (em, px and %), so it's quite difficult to give you an easy answer. Maybe reading [this](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm) might give some light on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is specificity and the cascade. The inspector always lists the selectors in the order of most specific to least specific. If two selectors have the same weight, then the cascade (source order) kicks in with the selector that came later winning out.

For example:

```css
p {
    color: white;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
}
/* ... bunch of other CSS here ... */
p {
    color: blue;
}
/* final rule */
p {
    color: blue;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
}
```

`font-size: 62.5%` on the `body` is used to set the base font size from `16px` to `10px` (16 x 0.625 = 10). Your media query is changing the base font size back to `16px` with `font-size: 100%` because it occurs later in the document.

Since `ems` are a relative measurement you'll have to either **not** change `font-size` in the media query to `100%` (effectively removing that selector) or add a media query for `#header p` changing the `em` value.

```css
@media(...) {
    #header p {
        font-size: 1.25em; /* 20/16 = 1.25 */
    }
}
```